# String cannot be of zero length

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

[image]

When I run my C# application on another systems it gives me this error !!
But everything is fine in my system. I think there is some missing dll, maybe?

Comment: This could be a component/class/method that doesn't accepts a parameter(string) with zero length, so it raises an exception. Did you forgot to complete the `.config`, so a empty setting is passed?

Comment: actually I am using telerik ,do I need any file which this component work on other system ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message it seems that you've got an textbox somewhere on your form with a mask applied to it? The default value in that box is not supplied, or does not conform to the mask set.

Just make sure you set a default text value conforming to any mask you have set. In the initialization you can try to clear it before rendering to the screen.

Comment: you are right @kroonwijk , I found the issue
I am using telerik maskededitbox.
already set MaskType:Numeric that in this situation works only in my system not others BUT when I set MaskType:Note it works in all systems.
but I need to set MaskType:Numric and Mask:n to show my number like 123,456
please help me on this ,notice that object is binded to sql

Comment: Can you make sure you use it something like this: <telerik:RadMaskedTextBox Margin="0,5,0,10" Mask="g" MaskType="Numeric" Value="111.234" />. Important is to specify the initial Value with a number. No matter what it is, it will be autoamtically replaced when the control is bound.

Comment: interesting piont is that , it is working on my system but on others raise that error !!!
I am sure that the initial value is 0

Comment: Try initial value 111.234? Maybe a zero collapses to an empty string in the mask ...

Comment: when use mask in telerik it doesnt let the user to change the value!

Comment: I used the following guidance to advise you: http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radmaskedtextbox-features-numeric-mask.html. Should be doable to initiate it with a value, according the documentation.

Comment: I set value to 0 in initialize component but not work,for let you know its not modifiable in properties box when set mask and mask type